# Flutter iOS build failes after adding zego_uikit_prebuilt_call package which uses awesome_notifications

Tags: swift, flutter, awesome-notifications

After adding zego_uikit_prebuilt_call package in my Flutter application the iOS app failed to build with the following error message:

```
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:59:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:60:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'e'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:73:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:87:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'e'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:341:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:364:23

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:370:23

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:461:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:486:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:511:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:535:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:559:19

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Type 'Logger' has no member 'd'
.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/awesome_notifications-0.7.7/ios/Classes/lib/SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.swift:583:19

....
```

Dependencies:

- cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
- zego_uikit_prebuilt_call: ^3.15.3

Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 13.4 22F66 darwin-arm64, locale en-EN)

I have tried all of the above steps, as well as the following (multiple times, multiple orders):

Upgrade Flutter to 3.13.6
  Upgrade XCode to version 15
  Upgrade cocoapods (brew upgrade cocoapods)
  delete podfile.lock
  delete Pods folder
  flutter clean
  flutter pub cache repair
  flutter pub get
  flutter pub upgrade
  cd into ios
  pod install —repo-update
  pod update

Cannot upgrade to awesome_notifications: ^0.8.2 because zego_uikit_prebuilt_call relies on awesome_notifications: ^0.7.4+1

Answer (score -1):

I just upgraded to latest version awesome_notifications: 0.8.2, Then run `pod update`

Answer (score -1):

Just update to latest verison

```
pod install
```